# how do I log in with python in a website that uses get method and not post method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm new to python and I need to log in to a website but I can only find articles and videos that talks about the POST method form login and I can't figure out how to login in a form that uses a GET method.
This code I believe is for the POST method isn't it?
The website I want to log in uses get method

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'
}

login_data = {
    'name': '<username>',
    'pass': '<password>',
    'form_id': 'new_login_form',
    'op': 'Login'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://www.codechef.com/'
    r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
    login_data['form_build_id'] = soup.find('input', attrs={'name': 'form_build_id'})['value']
    r = s.post(url, data=login_data, headers=headers)
    print(r.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure your question really is about python, and to solve your issue you would need more information on the authentication mechanism of your target website.

Even though you can send data in a GET request as parameters, it must always be avoided to transmit credentials and you will probably (hopefully) never see it used.

What you will find in a lot of cases in a login endpoint that will return you a token that you will use to retrieve content either by using it as a parameter of your request or inside the "Authorization" header.

Comment: I'm sorry but I figured out the stupidity of my question 1 minute after I posted it. I used the code that I sent before changing it to fit my needs, now that I'm logged in tho I have to figure out how to stay logged in and go to the page I need to scrape. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Since you are scraping, your authentication is probably done through a cookie that the request session should keep and add to any further request. So I think it should work on it's own. You can check if you have a cookie after login by printing s.cookie.